# Entity Framework - How to create custom index depend on other field

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have 2 entities:

```
public class Issue
{
   //Actualy is the Project key
    public int Id1 { get; set; }
    public int Id2 { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ISet<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
}
```

Id1 in Issue entity is a Project key. I Want Id2 to  increment depends on ProjectId. It should look like

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |

And {Id1, Id2} must be composite key to the Issue.
I don't understand how to do that except count issues with the same project key every time I add a value in the table.

Comment: I dont think you need a composite key, Id2 represents another entity ?

Comment: I disagree, I think Issue has a composite key, as it is a child of Project. @ProstoVitya, why don't you use SQL Server's IDENTITY property, which will auto-generate the Ids for you, and guarantees that they are unique? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16.

Comment: @Polyfun the IDENTITY does not ensure uniqueness. You can reseed to a value that will cause duplicates. It discusses that topic on the link you posted. But an identity is not going to solve the issue for this post. They want sequential numbers for each Issue per Project.

Comment: Why do you care if the ID for each Issue is sequential? What happens if an Issue is deleted? Sounds like you are relying to heavily on generated numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use SQL Server's IDENTITY property, which will auto-generate the Ids for you, and guarantees that they are unique. Otherwise you will have to do a SELECT MAX on Issue.Id2 where Issue.Id1 = *x* to find the current maximum Id2 for your chosen Id1, which will unnecessarily lock the table (bad for performance).

You can define the IDENTITY column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Issue
(  
  Id1 int not null,
  Id2 int IDENTITY(1, 1) not null
)
```

which will set the first value to 1, and increment by 1 for each subsequent row.

Project.Id could also be an IDENTITY column.

For details see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16.

Comment: Id2 souldnt be unique because I store issues for all projects in one table. It represents local id of an issue in project. I think similar issue indexing used in redmine.
May be I should use different approach?

Comment: Identity is NOT unique. This is a quote from the page you linked. `The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following:

Uniqueness of the value - Uniqueness must be enforced by using a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint or UNIQUE index.`